# Getting "malloc: *** error: incorrect checksum for freed object" inconsistently

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, block

The full error is:

```
app(85540,0x38661a8) malloc: *** error for object 0x11214f84: 
incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed.
```

So I'm getting something that is quite hard to replicate and I suspect is has something to do with the way I have my block set up. What I'm trying to get is the current online status of gamers on Xbox Live, so I allocate 2 `NSMutuableDictionaries` in `viewDidLoad`. `onlinePlayers` is for holding the online status values of the gamers so it's not checked over and over again in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` when scrolling up and down. `checkedPlayers` is to prevent multiple calls going out trying to get the status of the same player. Anyway, if I keep launching the simulator over and over again, it will be fine 29/30 launches, but it always crashes at least once on launch with the above error when I'm trying to set the online status value for a gamer:

```
        NSString* gamertag = cell.gamerTagLabel.text;
    if (![_checkedPlayers containsObject:gamertag]) {
        [_checkedPlayers addObject:gamertag];
        [Utilities processJSONDataWithGamertag:gamertag andBlock:^(NSData *jsonData) {
            id onlineStatus;
            NSDictionary *allXboxAttributes = [Utilities returnJSONObject:jsonData];
            // Get current Xbox Live Data
            if ([allXboxAttributes objectForKey:@"data"]) {
                NSDictionary *dataXboxAttributes = [allXboxAttributes objectForKey:@"data"];
                onlineStatus = [dataXboxAttributes objectForKey:@"online"];  

                // Crashes on the line below     
                [_onlinePlayers setObject:onlineStatus forKey:gamertag];

            // Return to main thread and update online status
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [self.tableView reloadData];
            });
        }];
    }
```

If it helps for some reason, the value being returned from `dataXboxAttributes` is a `BOOL`. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Turn on Memory diagnostics: Edit Scheme, Run, Diagnostics. That will check for improper re-use.

Comment: Thanks, do I need to use instruments at all along with this or just keep launching until it happens again?

Comment: This is independent of instruments. Note that no memory is released so eventually an iPhone will run out of memory, the simulator should be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from your code it looks like the completion block of processJSON isnt always on the main thread, synchronize access to onlinePlayers.

`@synchronized` will do I guess

Comment: This is what I wound up doing. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You are getting the error in that method but the problem might be elsewhere.

To find the source of the problem, in XCode go to Product > Scheme > Edit Scheme, and under Diagnostics tab enable all the Malloc settings and Guard Malloc.

With that, run your application again, and XCode will stop at the line causing the problem.

[image: Scheme definition]